# How can I do a "one hit" Linq query with nullable values?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```
public class MyTrelloCard
{
    ...
    public DateTime? completed { get; set; }
    public Decimal? estHours { get; set; }
    public bool complete { get; set; }
}
```

...and I want to query the number of estHours on each date in the completed date. These have to be nullable values as not every card is completed, and not every card has estimated hours added to it.

At the moment I have to run two queries. The first one:

```
List<burnDownData> bData = (from c in cards
                            where c.complete
                            group c by new
                            {
                                date = Convert.ToDateTime(c.completed).Date
                            } into g
                            select new burnDownData
                            {
                                date = g.Key.date,
                                completedHours = g.Sum(x=>x.estHours) ?? 0
                            }).ToList();
```

returns all the cards that have been completed.

The second one is used to iterate through all dates between a start and end period and cumulatively add up the completed hours:

```
for (DateTime d = start; d.Date <= end; d = d.AddDays(1))
{
    if ((d.DayOfWeek >= DayOfWeek.Monday) && (d.DayOfWeek <= DayOfWeek.Friday))
    {
        List<C> values = new List<C>();

        Decimal xx = (from b in bData
                      where b.date.Date == d
                      select b.completedHours).SingleOrDefault();

        total = total + xx;

        values.Add(new C { v = d.ToString("d MMM") });
        values.Add(new C { v = total.ToString() });

        myRows.Add(new Row { c = values });
    }
}
```

This seems inefficient though. Is it possible to do this directly? i.e. to replace this part of the loop:

```
Decimal xx = (from b in bData
              where b.date.Date == d
              select b.completedHours).SingleOrDefault();
```

With something that queries the `cards` data directly?

Comment: You question would be a lot more readable if you'd take a bit of time to format your code pleasantly. (And follow .NET naming conventions...)

Comment: Also, it's not really clear what your question has to do with nullable values. Can't you just use `where b.date.Date >= start && b.date.Date <= end`?

Comment: My issue is I can't query using b.date.Date until I have run the query to effectively strip out the null dates. (i.e. converting from (the admittedly badly named) cards to bData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - so you want an entry for every weekday in your range, even if no data exists for that day. In which case, build an array of eligible days, and groupjoin your cards.

Here's how:

```
var start = DateTime.Today;
var end = start.AddDays(14);

var cards = new[]{new {complete = true, completed = (DateTime?)DateTime.Now, estHours = new decimal?(3)} };

var days = Enumerable.Range(0, end.Subtract(start).Days)
.Select(x => start.AddDays(x))
.Where(x => !new []{DayOfWeek.Saturday,DayOfWeek.Sunday}.Contains(x.DayOfWeek));

var results = from d in days
              join c in cards on d equals c.completed.GetValueOrDefault().Date
              into cGrp
              select new {d, completedHours = cGrp.Sum(x => x.estHours)};
```

of course you don't need the `var cards =` line, as you already have your own source for that!

**Edit** - All timestamps for a day are grouped into the 1 day.

Comment: I think I missed some information off here. In cards, the complete field is a full timestamp (ie with a date and a time) so the join won't work. Can I do this in this query, or do I need to do a Cartesian product first?

Comment: You can do it in the query @Ben - just change `.completed` to `.completed.GetValueOrDefault().Date` in the join - as shown in the edited answer above

Answer (score 2):

Interpreting your question:

> I want to query the number of estHours on each date in the completed
> date. These have to be nullable values as not every card is completed,
> and not every card has estimated hours added to it

...as "I'm trying to get a sum of estimated hours for each `completed` date instance, and want to allow for null `completed` and `estHours` values".
You could include the check for null in your Where clause:

```
var x = cards.Where(c => c.completed != null )
    .GroupBy(c => c.completed, (key, group) => new
    {
        dateComp = key.Value,
        totEstHrs = group.Sum(i => i.estHours)
    });
x.ToList().ForEach(
    item => Debug.Print("{0:MM/dd/yyyy} {1}", item.dateComp, item.totEstHrs));
```

For example:

```
List<MyTrelloCard> cards = new List<MyTrelloCard>() {
    new MyTrelloCard() { completed = new DateTime(2014, 4, 28), estHours = 5,    complete = true },
    new MyTrelloCard() { completed = null,                      estHours = 5,    complete = false },
    new MyTrelloCard() { completed = null,                      estHours = null, complete = true },
    new MyTrelloCard() { completed = new DateTime(2014, 4, 28), estHours = 7,    complete = false },
    new MyTrelloCard() { completed = new DateTime(2014, 4, 29), estHours = null, complete = false },
    new MyTrelloCard() { completed = new DateTime(2014, 4, 29), estHours = 3,    complete = false },
};
```

Produces:

> 04/28/2014 12
>
> 04/29/2014 3

**Edit:**
To group on just the date portion (omitting the timestamp) you can group on the [`ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) value:

```
var x = cards.Where(c => c.completed != null)
    .GroupBy(c =>
        ((DateTime)c.completed).ToShortDateString(),
        (key, group) => new
        {
            dateComp = key,
            totEstHrs = group.Sum(i => i.estHours)
        });
```